# Nuxtjs Svg binding of xlink:href doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, svg, nuxt.js

I am not able to get the svg xlink:href work as a dynamic property in Nuxtjs(Vue). I am trying to use it like below

```
 <svg class="icon phone-icon">
        <use
          v-bind="{ 'xlink:href': '../assets/sprite.svg#icon-download' }"
        ></use>
      </svg>
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt does not process any string value in any object to check if it is a link or not, Use `require` to find the public path of your SVG

```
<svg class="icon phone-icon">
    <use
        v-bind="{ 'xlink:href': require('../assets/sprite.svg') + '#icon-download' }"
    ></use>
</svg>
```

Also, take a look at [SVG Sprite Module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/svg-sprite-module/), this module creates a clean way to work with SVG icons

Comment: Thanks for the SVG module. I used a svg4everybody like here https://github.com/nuxt-community/svg-sprite-module/issues/42#issuecomment-516056532  but it doesn't seem to work in IE11. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I didn't test `svg4everybody`, you can reopen that issue, explain problem and ask folks on github

Answer (score 0):

On NuxtJS 2 I had to do the following:

```
<svg class="icon">
    <use v-bind="{ 'xlink:href': require('~/assets/sprite.svg') + '#icon-download' }"></use>
</svg>
```

without `~` it did not work.